# How to make usable .group(:ip).count in AciveRecord(Rails)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have controller in Rails with table that have data like to sample data below:

```
download_trackers
[{ id: 1, file_name: "test.zip", ip: "192.168.0.27" },
 { id: 2, file_name: "test.zip", ip: "192.168.0.27" },
 { id: 3, file_name: "test.zip", ip: "192.168.0.20" }]
```

I want to get data that will be grouped by `ip`, same to code below:

```
DownloadTracker.group(:ip).count
#=> {"192.168.0.20"=>1, "192.168.0.27"=>2}
```

But this will returns a key value pair of count and IP address. But I want all columns of first record in given group with count as separate column in result.

How I can achieve this?

Comment: How is `DownloadTracker.group(:ip).count` not usable? Looks perfectly fine to me.

Comment: what type of data you exactly want??

Comment: @VishalJAIN array of objects

Comment: Then why use `count`?

Comment: @D-side .count used to show what data i want to get, that's only reason why i used it.

Comment: But that clearly returns the type of data you **don't** want. I'm at loss about what you need.

Comment: can you put here some sample data of what you want.

Comment: @D-side To simplify example of result - i want to get Data same as DownloadTracker.all that will contain 1 more field: count.

Comment: That doesn't make sense :) Every record would be present in the output only once. By grouping, what values are you expecting to see in the other attributes that are not grouped? `.group(:ip).count` gave you sensible result: a hash of pairs `IP => occurrences`.

Comment: @D-side in my case that 2 fields will be enough. How can i call these result in my view?

Comment: hey you can try this way `DownloadTracker.select("download_trackers.*,count(*) as count").group("ip")` it will give you your require answer but not similar to `DownloadTracker.all` because group is here. otherwise your group doesn't makes sense

Comment: @VishalJAIN that exactly is what i wanted to get. Can you add it to the answer and edit my question that blown your brain? I want to rate it because it was impossible to find the same usage anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey you can find all columns of given table with count and all fields of given table with group using

```
  @trackers = DownloadTracker.select("download_trackers.*,count(*) as count").group("ip")
```

> It will return you first record of given group with count of given group in count column

If you want access count simply used

```
@trackers.first.count
```

If you want to print current result with count field on console used `as_json` serializer as

```
@trackers.as_json
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your dataset from `DownloadTracker.group(:ip).count` is perfectly usable. It's not an array, it's a `Hash`, a set of **key**-*value* pairs. In this case, **keys are IPs**, *values are numbers of occurrences for each IP*.

You can iterate over it like so:

```
DownloadTracker.group(:ip).count.each do |ip, count|
  # whatever you want
end
```

And it's not something Rails-related, it's **a pure-Ruby way to traverse a hash**. While many say that learning Rails without Ruby is OK, you're already on the level where it's no longer acceptable. So you should start familiarizing yourself with the language now :)